# Is question mark really need when select all row in prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I wonder if I still need question mark if I don't want to specify any row. Because `bind_param` needs it.

```
$zr="0";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from products_db where not prd_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$zr);//can I skip this line or what?
```

I search everywhere but there's no such a thing. Once I tried without `?` it errors without reason. I might be typo error, something?

Comment: FYI, no program ever _"errors without reason"_. If you can't see the errors, it just means your environment is not configured to show them. See [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) and [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to bind any parameters, you can use [`mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.query.php)

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM products_db');
```

This both prepares and executes the SQL provided but offers no way to safely bind parameters.

This is roughly equivalent to...

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM products_db');
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

which you can also use.

Note there are no positional parameters (ie `?`) and therefore, no need to use `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`.